# Can't enable UFW on remote server - it blocks SSH no matter the config

Tags: server, ssh, firewall, ufw

I want to set up ufw on remote machine while connecting by SSH. 
I type

```
ufw reset
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default allow outgoing

ufw allow ssh
ufw allow 22
ufw enable
```

And after that it immediately blocks ssh connection, and does not accept new ones. The only thing I can do is to reset the server. 
Did I miss something?

EDIT 1: OF cause I do have ssh configured. I am accessing server by SSH. This means it is configured and that I have connection to the server until I run `ufw enable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently having the same issue. For now, I did this as a workaround.

```
ufw default allow incoming
ufw deny 1:21/tcp
ufw deny 23:65535/tcp
```

Comment: May I ask if your problematic machine is ARM or other non-x86?

Comment: I am a Windows person so unfortunately I do know how to check it. However, it is a BareMetal instance with 11.99€ price [here](https://www.scaleway.com/pricing/)

Comment: Try typing `file /bin/bash`. For my desktop it says `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64`, for my ARM server it is `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1`

Comment: Mine says `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64`.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on a fresh install worked fine for me, even after a reboot, on Ubuntu 16.04.2

```
ufw enable
ufw allow ssh
ufw allow 22
ufw enable
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using `expect` command:

```
apt install expect -y

if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] || [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then
  expect -c "
    set timeout 3
    spawn ufw enable

    expect \"Command may disrupt existing ssh connections\"
    send -- \"y\r\"
    expect eof
"
else
  ufw enable
fi

apt purge expect -y
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/ufw.8.html#remote%20management) you can enable ufw remotely by:

```
ufw --force enable
```

In this case it won't ask for confirmation, so above command can be used in bash script.